# Como obtener un valor de un <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, genexus

Tengo la siguiente estructura :

```html
<span class="ErrorViewer">
 <menu>
   <li>El Porcentaje de la prima del contrato es menor que el porcentaje Aprobado por la GERENTE </li>
 </menu>
```

Me gustaría mostrar una alerta con el texto que esta dentro del `<li>` utilizando JS o JQuery

Comment: Pon un identificador a tu `<menu>`, luego podrás acceder a él desde JS o jQuery.

Comment: gracias por sus comentarios y el tiempo que se han tomado para atender mi pregunta, pero el problema que el sistema esta hecho en genexus y cuando ocurre un error, este me refresca la pantalla y me crea la estructura anterior y esto no se puede modificar agregándole un id. @juan-pinzón

Comment: Tu quieres que se muestre tu alert cuando "dinamicamente" te arroje el Error; El porcentaje bla.. bla... ? o el usuario va hacer click sobre este error y es ahí donde deberá mostrar el alert.

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco seria dinamicamente, que el codigo js busque la etiqueta en todo mi documento html y recupere el valor que seria el mensaje.

Comment: @N.Zaldivar te agregue un código espero te pueda servir, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno entonces asumiendo que el "error" será dinámico (*por decirlo de alguna forma*) entonces vamos hacer lo siguiente:

```js
/*Todo esto código solo es para silumar cuando se lanza el error*/
var btn = document.getElementById("lanza");
btn.onclick = function(){
   var spanError = '<span class="error"><menu><li>texto del error</li></menu></span>';
   this.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',spanError);
}

var btnSaludo = document.getElementById("saludo");
btnSaludo.onclick = function(){
  var spanSaludo = '<span class="saludo"><menu><li>HOLA COMO ESTAS</li></menu>';
  btn.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',spanSaludo);
}
/*Aqui termina digamos el simulador; cuando sale el error*/
/*Ahora si comenzamos con el código que debes mas centrarte
Pues bien, creamos un Event Listener donde vamos a agregarselo a todo el body danto como evento los clicks
*/
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function() { //cuando se ejecute un click en el body entra esta función anonima
  var a = document.querySelector("span.error"); //Buscamos si tenemos en el documento algun elemento span con una class .error
  if(a != undefined || a != null){ //Confirmamos que si haya un elemento
      alert(a.outerText); //Cuando si encontremos un elemento, entonces lanzamos un alert con el texto que se contiene en el elemento li
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="lanza">lanzar error</button>
<button id="saludo">lanzar saludo</button>
```

Ahora, le hace mucho mas que programar a este código, pero ya puedes tu tropicalizarlo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: Si el código te ha servido, debes elegirlo para los futuros Usuarios SO. La Pregunta tendría una respuesta aceptada. Esto debes hacerlo en la respuesta que tu consideras que es la que te ha servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Osea algo como esto

```js
alert($("span.ErrorViewer menu li").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="ErrorViewer">
 <menu>
   <li>El Porcentaje de la prima del contrato es menor que el porcentaje Aprobado por la GERENTE </li>
 </menu>
```

Aqui bindeamos el evento click a todos los `li`, que esten dentro del elmento `menu` y con el `this` y `text()` mandamos su valor al `alert`

Comment: gracias por sus comentarios y el tiempo que se han tomado para atender mi pregunta, pero el problema que el sistema esta hecho en genexus y cuando ocurre un error, este me refresca la pantalla y me crea la estructura anterior y esto no se puede modificar agregándole un id.

Comment: @N.Zaldivar que bueno que comentas eso, en mi solución no necesita agregar el id, simplemente utiliza la estructura que pusiste en la pregunta

Comment: Correcto y gracias, pero el asunto es que Genexus me sobrescribe mi HTML para mostrar este mensaje la idea es detectar si existe <span class="ErrorViewer"> y si existe mostrar el mensaje en un alert(..) y si no pues no hará nada

Comment: @N.Zaldivar Ok, hice una actualizacion, en este caso toma los li dentro de menu que esten dentro de el ErrorViewer, en caso de ho haber error no se mostraria nada

Comment: Gracias, solo permiteme lo implementare y te comento como me va

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el texto del tag `<li>` agregale un id al mismo y luego usa la funcion `text()` de jquery por ejemplo:

```js
alert($("#demo").text());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<span class="ErrorViewer">
 <menu>
   <li id="demo">El Porcentaje de la prima del contrato es menor que el porcentaje Aprobado por la GERENTE 
   </li>
 </menu>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias por sus comentarios y el tiempo que se han tomado para atender mi pregunta, pero el problema que el sistema esta hecho en genexus y cuando ocurre un error, este me refresca la pantalla y me crea la estructura anterior y esto no se puede modificar agregándole un id